# Stop/Interrupt threads blocked on waiting input from socket

Tags: java, multithreading

As the title says I need a way to stop or interrupt  a thread that is blocked waiting on an input from the socket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Thread.interrupt()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) should be the method you're looking for.
Be sure that your input-accessing methods also check for InterruptedException and ClosedByInterruptException.

Also look at the corresponding [page in the Sun Concurrency Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), as another solution suggests.

Comment: unfortunately, Thread.interrupt() has no effect on the BufferedInputStream.read().

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere this is because BufferedInputStream does itself not operate on interruptable resources (eg. a socket) but only on other Streams. Only if this source stream works on an interruptable resource (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html for a list of channesl which support interruption) the Thread.interrupt() causes the thread to interrupt.

Answer (score 12):

You could simply close() the IO stream/socket from another thread. Then, you could check on a volatile boolean field if the resulting IOException is due the close or something else. I think the close might result in an `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` exception.

Comment: Using Exceptions for program flow control is very bad style, especially if it is general purpose ones like "IOException" which could be caused by a variety of things other than timeouts in this case.

Comment: You misunderstood me. If you close a socket, the read() throws an IOException - in this case a SocketException. You already have a try-catch for the IOException. If you use Thread.interrupt() it causes an exception to be thrown too. Therefore, you always get some exception. I suggested adding a flag to indicate there was an deliberate cancel/close attempt before the read threw an exception.

Comment: Couldn't a _true_ IOException be thrown between the time you set the flag and call `close()`?

Answer (score 6):

Sockets allow to set a timeout via the `setSoTimeout()` method. This is the preferred way to stop them blocking.

Otherwise you might want to have a look at the `nio` package which allows for non-blocking I/O at the expense of more manual work to manage incoming and outgoing data.

Comment: +1. I'd go with running while loop with timeout rather than killing the thread.

Comment: Using NIO might be too complex for a simple Cancel operation. Btw,
"Using Exceptions for program flow control is very bad style" unfortunately, setSoTimeout will result in SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: Setting a timeout to handle cancellation is definitely the wrong thing to do; it means cancelling has to sit around until the read times out.

Comment: What I intended was for the socket to time out eventually. You would not want to have a network connection blocking the UI for *any* time, so in many cases it will be just fine to fire up a background task with the socket. Cancellation can then be handled differently for the UI and the background task at a later time.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see `socket.closeInput()`. However, I did find `socket.shutdownInput()`. After calling that (from a different thread that was blocking on the read naturally), my call to `bufferedReader.close()` worked fine! (I followed that with calls to `printWriter.close()` and `socket.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sock.closeInput() followed by sock.close()

Answer (score 0):

Close the socket and the read will be unblocked (will exit with a subclass of IOException). Read reacting to Thread.interrupt is platform dependent (won't work on Solaris 10 for example).