# How to degrade a program gracefully when there are waiting threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, graceful-degradation

I know the construct of terminating a thread gracefully:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable {
   private volatile boolean stop = false;

   public void stop() {
      stop = true;
   }

   public void run() {
      while (!stop) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

But if some thread is waiting for something, inside some object (using `wait()`, without time limit), then this construct won't be useful to stopping this thread, because he is already past the condition in the while loop, so he will continue forever.

So, what is the right way to stop the waiting threads?

Comment: Your construct is not correct, the `stop` variable must be `volatile`

Comment: @Leif Ericson: actually if your program is multi-threaded you're probably calling the *stop()* method from another thread: you hence want to change *private boolean stop = false* to *private volatile boolean stop = false* because otherwise there's no guarantee that the *run()* method would read the correct *stop* value after you changed it from another thread.

Comment: @denis Your first statement is correct (OP's construct is not correct). Your second statement is not correct, as you could also use a method call.

Comment: @denis I mean if you did `while(!shouldStop())` you wouldn't need to make it `volatile`. Your statement says it must be `volatile` which while being the simplest solution is not the only solution. Only the Sith deal in absolutes (except Jedi making observations about Sith).

Comment: @glowcoder if you did `while(!shouldStop())` you would need to mark both `shoudlStop()` and `stop()` as `synchronized`. In this case, yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Thread is *actually* waiting for something, you should call the method [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) to interrupt the thread. Instead of checking for your custom variable in the while loop, use Thread.isInterrupted() or Thread.interrupted() - one resets the interruption flag, the other doesn't.

If you are waiting on something, I assumed you had to catch the [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html), didn't you?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your threads to wait indefinitely, don't code them to do that in the first place. You're writing their code, so write it to do what you actually so you don't have to try to fix it from the outside.

Comment: I don't have a choice. The threads have to wait in part of my program. I could use `wait(X)` but I can't just throw a random number.

Comment: If you want the threads to wait indefinitely, code them to do that. But don't code them to wait indefinitely and then complain that they wait indefinitely. Put some thought into exactly what you want the threads to do and then code them to do that. That way, you won't have to find a way to "make them" do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Every well-behaved blocking method declares a the checked exception `InterruptedException`, which serves this exact purpose: to notify that the thread has been interrupted while it was blocked.

You have to catch this exception, and actually this could replace your `stop` field.

For instance, let's consider a logging system that will write messages to a file on a dedicated thread (so that the time spent on IO will not interfere in your application -- assuming it is not IO heavy).

Every thread has an *initerrupted flag* that can be read through `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. You try something like this:

```
class Logger {
  private final File file = ...;
  private final BlockingQueue<String> logLines = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
  private final Thread loggingThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override public void run() {
      PrintWriter pw;
      try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          try {
            pw.println(logLines.take());
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // good habit: make sure the interrupt status is set
          }
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
      } catch (IOException e) { ... flush and close pw if not null and open ... }
    }
  });
  { loggingThread.start(); }
  public void log(final String line) { logLines.offer(line); } // will always work, because logLines is a LinkedBQ.
  public void stop() { loggingThread.interrupt(); }
}
```

Finally, for a graceful shutdown of your application, you must be sure to terminate this thread before letting the JVM shutdown. To do so, you must either be absolutely certain to call `stop()` before shutting down in any possible way, or you could register a shutdown hook, by adding something like this instance initializer to the class:

```
class Logger {
  ...
  {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() { close(); }
    }));
  }
}
```

This will force the JVM to call close() (therefore interrupting the thread, flushing and closing the file) before terminating.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on why you have to wait in your thread. If the thread is waiting on an uninterruptible IO, then you can take a look at [Stop/Interrupt threads blocked on waiting input from socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024482/stop-interrupt-threads-blocked-on-wainting-input-from-socket)

Otherwise it all depends on how you wait in the thread. You could use `wait(1000)`, then check for the flag and wait some more. You could wait for a message from a blocking queue, you could use locks/conditions, even `wait/notify` could work in this case you would need to handle interrupts properly.