# Interrupt a thread performing a long running database select

Tags: java, spring

My requirement is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024482/stop-interrupt-threads-blocked-on-wainting-input-from-socket) one except that my long running IO operation is a database select.

One rather rather creative solution suggested in that thread, involved closing the IO stream in a separate thread. However, I don't really have a reference to the input stream or socket.

I can't even close the connection being used as I use spring-jdbc, which does not provide me access to the underlying connection being used. I believe `JdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` will potentially return another connection from the data source.

Appreciate any help/suggestions i can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JdbcTemplate.execute(PreparedStatementCreator, PreparedStatementCallback)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCallback%29)

In the PreparedStatementCreator, you get access to the Statement, which you can give to another thread. This other thread creates a timer and calls .cancel on the Statement if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As Istvan Mentioned, PreparedStatementCreator is the way to go. 
Pasting my implementation in case its helpful ..

```
private final long timeout = 1000; //timeout in seconds
final SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        if (timeout>0){
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new ConnectionInterrupter(con), timeout*1000);
        }
        return con.prepareStatement(queryString);
    }
}, new ResultSetExtractor<SqlRowSet>() {
    @Override
    public SqlRowSet extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        CachedRowSet rowSet = newCachedRowSet();
        rowSet.populate(rs);
        return new ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet(rowSet);
    }

    protected CachedRowSet newCachedRowSet() throws SQLException {
        return new CachedRowSetImpl();
    }
});
private class ConnectionInterrupter extends TimerTask {
    private final Connection connection;
    public ConnectionInterrupter(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            logger.warn("Connection timeout has occurred. Manually closing the connection ...");
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```